# how to listen to an xml file and update the view when content changes? android

Tags: android, xml

now i have an app that read the xml file from internet, how to listen to this file and notify the user whenever the content has changed on the server side? so that user don't need to press refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `AlarmManager` class, and `setRepeating` method.
It will help you to create a repeating action for reading the xml file.
See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)

Comment: thank you. but does it consume much system resources and buttery? do you have any ideas how does the facebook notification work?

Comment: I don't know how it really work behind. I believe that Facebook use this action to. It one of the Android API, I'm sure it was written in the best way and there is no need to implement it yourself. And yes, of course it takes more battery power. But I do not think it's significant. I think that using thread for this kind of task, will consume more resources.

Comment: thanks, i found another good stuff, google cloud messaging, quite handy

Comment: Google cloud messaging is connector between server and cellphones. If the xml is yours and the server is yours you can use it